# How to get a value from inside a hash in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the `organization_id` in this for each by doing this

```
output.each do |cta|      
  puts cta['organization_id']
end
```

This is what cta prints out:

```
9763u5r169w6
{"domain"=>"test.test.com", "api_key"=>"**********", "flow_id"=>5, "email"=>"test@test.com", "organization_id"=>1}
```

I have tried doing it in the following ways with no luck also:

```
puts cta[0]['organization_id']
puts cta[0][:organization_id]
puts cta[:organization_id]
```

how can i get the organization_id out of cta?

EDIT: this is what output looks like

```
{
    "7t6tqrwvnt37" => {
        "domain" => "test.test.com", "api_key" => "************", "flow_id" => 5, "email" => "test@test.com", "organization_id" => 1
    }, "9mwe71j08a3c" => {
        "domain" => "test.test.com", "api_key" => ""************",", "flow_id" => 5, "email" => "test@test.com", "organization_id" => 1
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `output` look like?

Comment: just edited the question to show the output @SimpleLime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a hash of hashes, where the key for the hash value is a unique string. However, you are not concern with the keys, so simply look through each hash value and treat this as the hash you want to retrieve from.

```
output.each do |key, value|
  puts value['organization_id']
end
```

The difference here between your code and mine, is that without two outputs for this enumerator block, the value `cta` is only the hash keys.

Comment: Thank you i was smashing my head trying everything, i'm so bad with these hashes

Comment: I may be mistaken, but without two outputs for this enumerator block, I believe the value `cta` is an `Array`. Which is why Michale Yurkovetc's answer also works. No?

Comment: @jvillian I will test this out and edit my answer if true.

Comment: @jvillian this is false and my last paragraph holds. Whenever only one output defined for the block, this variable is still the `key`. This means that the `value` will never be available in the block, making `cta[n][key]` invalid.

Comment: Hm. Very odd. In my console, if I do like RickS originally did (using only `|cta|` and not `|key, value|`) and inside the each loop do `puts cta.class.name`, I get `Array`. Also, I tried `puts cta[1]['organization_id']` as Michael suggested and that seemed to work just fine. Also, if `cta` is only the hash keys, then the OP's `cta` print wouldn't include the hash as the second element of the array, which it clearly does.

Comment: I do not doubt that the returned block variable is an array of keys and that adding the value returns an array of values. But these are keys only, please refer to the following for more https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each .

Answer (score 1):

The output you provided has a typo in it for the second child hash. But I think this should do what you want.

```
cta = { "7t6tqrwvnt37"=> { "domain"=>"test.test.com", "api_key"=>"************", "flow_id"=>5, "email"=>"test@test.com", "organization_id"=>1 },
        "9mwe71j08a3c"=> { "domain"=>"test.test.com", "api_key"=>"************", "flow_id"=>5, "email"=>"test@test.com", "organization_id"=>1 } }

# Loop over hash and print organization_id value.
cta.each do |key, value|
  puts value["organization_id"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

output is hash object
so below code give correct value

`output.each do |k,v|
  puts v['organization_id']
 end`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
output.each do |cta|
  puts cta[1]['organization_id']
end
```